# Def.sequential and exceptions

Tags: sbt

`Def.sequential` allows to execute several tasks sequentially:

```
myTask := {
  Def.sequential(task1, task2, task3)
}
```

If `task1` fails (throws an exception) then the remaining tasks aren't executed.

This is in constrast with the following, which always executes all tasks:

```
myTask := {
  task1.value
  task2.value
  task3.value
}
```

What's the best way of executing all of them sequentially, even if some of them fail, and report errors?.

I want to execute tests, and to know which of them have problems.  They can't be executed in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is:

```
task1 := doTask1()
task2 := doTask2()
task3 := doTask3()

myTask := {
  val results = Seq(
    Try { doTask1() },
    Try { doTask2() },
    Try { doTask3() }
  )
  results foreach {
    case Failure(e) =>
        sys.error(e.getMessage)
    case _ =>
  }
}
```

but for built-in tasks like `compile`, `test` it isn't easy to know the implmemntation.